# Does EntityFramework work against an Access 2007 db (.accdb)?

Tags: entity-framework, ms-access

I'm trying to create an MVC application that uses an Access 2007 DB (.accdb).  I can create the Model using DataSet.  But if I try to create a Model using EntityFramework, I can't get past VS2008 wanting to make the connection string be a SQL server.  Am I missing something, or does EF not play with Access?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648116/how-can-i-use-ms-access-as-a-provider-for-ado-net-entity-framework

Answer (score 7):

The Entity Framework works only with ADO.NET providers that support it. To use your Access database, I assume you use the OleDB provider, which doesn't support EF. Microsoft provides only two ADO.NET providers that support EF : SQL Server, and SQL Server CE. However you can find third party providers for other DBMS :

- [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
- [DevArt providers](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/linq.html) for several DBMS (commercial)

There are probably many others, but as far as I know, nothing for Access (which IMHO in not much of a DBMS anyway...)

Comment: There was really no need for that last parenthetical. Why don't you edit that out of your answer, which was otherwise ust fine?

Comment: If what you say is true, what about using SQL Server and a linked server to get to Access/Jet/ACE? Then you could go through SQL Server and get to the Jet/ACE data as though it were SQL Server data, no?

Comment: perhaps... to be honest, I'm not even sure what you're talking about... do you mean that you can query another database through SQL Server, similarly to Oracle's DB links ?

Comment: SQL Server allows you do mount other SQL Servers and Jet/ACE databases as "linked servers" and then you can use them from your SQL Server database. It's kind of like Access linked tables. I would assume that's what Oracle provides, too, but I know nothing about Oracle (none of my clients are foolish enough to use such an expensive database).

Comment: OK... so it might be an option indeed