# Entity framework join to ms-access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ms-access

I want to ask you is any way to generate or updating access database from entity framework, I have a serious problem I have a database using ms-access and it is expensive for me if I want to change to sql server ?

I need to use entity framework functionality. could you give me a solution ?

Comment: yes, change to SQL Server, or don't use EF.

Comment: there isn't any driver ?

Comment: i want to use entity framwork and supported databases are SQL server, SQL Compact and Microsoft Access. Does EF will work with all of them? Is it real that Access doesnt have driver to work with EF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does EntityFramework work against an Access 2007 db (.accdb)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231949/does-entityframework-work-against-an-access-2007-db-accdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use MSAccess don't use EF. If you want use EF, don't use MSAccess.
Entity Framework does not support Access. But you can migrate to SQL Express (at no cost) and use EF for your applications.
SQL Express is free and enought for small databases.

Alternatively, if you want a desktop database, you can use SQLite. NET driver for sqlite supports EF.